# Wait till promises inside interval done in unit tests

Tags: javascript, jestjs, sinon

(This seems partially overlapping with my previous question: [Test interaction with two interval async functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70576907/test-interaction-with-two-interval-async-functions))

Using jest 27.5.1 and sinon 13.0.1, I want to unit-test an async interval function.

Consider this code:

```
const fs = require("fs")
const { exec } = require("child_process")

module.exports = class MyClass {
    init() {
        setInterval(this.checkFileContent, 10)
    }
    
    async checkFileContent() {
            await new Promise((resolve) => { exec("sleep 0.4", resolve) })
            const fileContent = (await fs.promises.readFile("foo.txt")).toString()
            console.log(fileContent)
    }
}
```

and this test file

```
const MyClass = require(".")
const fs = require("fs")
const sinon = require("sinon")
const { exec } = require("child_process")

describe("MyClass", () => {
    let sandbox
    beforeAll(async () => {
        sandbox = sinon.createSandbox()
        await fs.writeFileSync("foo.txt", "fooContent")
    })

    afterAll(async () => {
        await fs.unlinkSync("foo.txt")
        await new Promise((resolve) => { exec("sleep 0.8", resolve) })
        sandbox.verifyAndRestore()
    })

    test("should test MyClass", async () => {
        const clock = sandbox.useFakeTimers()
        const instance = new MyClass()
        instance.init()
        clock.next()
        await Promise.resolve() // As suggested in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52196951/2710714 - but doesn't seem to help at all
        clock.reset()
    })
})
```

Running the test, I'll always get `ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'foo.txt'`. The reason being that `await fs.unlinkSync("foo.txt")` has already run when `await fs.promises.readFile("foo.txt")` is reached.

So, I need to somehow make sure that all promises in the `interval` function started by `clock.next()` are resolved before the tests stops. How do I do that?

Note: In real-life, it's not about file access but database queries. And the `exec("sleep ..."` is of course something artificial to replicate long-lasting operations. But the principles should be the same.

Edit: Also tried `await clock.nextAsync()` - didn't help.

Comment: `setInterval(this.checkFileContent, 10)` call `this.checkFileContent` every 10ms and never stop. So `Wait till promises inside interval done in unit tests` would wait forever?

Comment: @t.niese The Sinon docs (https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/fake-timers/): say about `clock.next()`: `Advances the clock to the the moment of the first scheduled timer, firing it.` In my understanding, that implies that the `interval` would run only once - as opposed to `clock.runAll`.